# Better way to repaint the jframe

Tags: java

I'm building a project for college and I have several shapes in my frame and I need to do some operations with those objects. for example:

```
Figure fig = figs.get(figs.size() -1);
fig.mov(dx,dy);
figs.set(figs.size() -1, fig);
repaint();
```

I have a array of figures and every time I drag/move 1 figure, I have to update that array and also do `repaint()` and this is going to happen when one of the keyboard arrows get pressed.

My problem here is that despite the repaint() function being fast, when I make several moves of 1 object, the screen goes white several times, making it difficult to see. I don't know a lot of java and I don't have any ideas of how to solve this. I was wondering if anyone has any ideas to help me out, please.

Example:

figurestest/Figure.java

```
package figurestest;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public abstract class Figure {
    public int x, y;
    public int w, h;

    public Figure (int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
    }

    public abstract void paint (Graphics g);
    public abstract void mov (int dx, int dy);
}
```

figurestest/rect.java

```
package figurestest;

import java.awt.*;

public class Rect extends Figure {

    public Rect (int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        super(x, y, w, h);
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        g2d.drawRect(this.x,this.y, this.w,this.h);
    }

    public void mov (int dx, int dy){

    this.x += dx;
    this.y += dy;
    }
}
```

testapp.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;


import figurestest.*;

class TestApp {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ListFrame frame = new ListFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}

class ListFrame extends JFrame {
    ArrayList<Figure> figs = new ArrayList<Figure>();
    Random rand = new Random();

    ListFrame () {
        this.addWindowListener (
            new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing (WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        );

        this.addKeyListener (
            new KeyAdapter() {
                public void keyPressed (KeyEvent evt) {
                Dimension size = getContentPane().getSize();
                
                int x = rand.nextInt(size.width);
                int y = rand.nextInt(size.height);
                int w = 5+ rand.nextInt(50);
                int h = 5+ rand.nextInt(50);
                if (evt.getKeyChar() == 'r') {
                    figs.add(new Rect(x,y, w,h));
                    } 
                else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP ) {
                    if (figs.size() > 0){
                        int dx = 0;
                        int dy = 0;
                        if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) dy = 2;
                        else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){ dy = -2;}
                        else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) dx = 2;
                        else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) dx = -2;
                            
                        
                        Figure fig = figs.get(figs.size() -1);
                        fig.mov(dx,dy);
                        figs.set(figs.size() -1, fig);


                    }
                
                }
                repaint(); 
                
                }
                
            }
        );

        this.setTitle("Figures");
        this.setSize(350, 350);
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        for (Figure fig: this.figs) {
            fig.paint(g);
        }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: general "programming with arrays/lists" note: you don't need to `figs.set` after updating your figure, because that's where it lives already. `figs.get` doesn't remove anything. JFrames are double buffered, so you should never see white flickering, so it would be a good idea to show [mcve] code in this case. Remember: it doesn't need to do what your real program does, it just needs to be "your program, with all the code that isn't related to the problem removed", which would basically just be a JFrame with a mouse handler, and the tiniest `Figure` class with only a constructor and `mov` method

Comment: Could you add a minimal reproducible example? My general advice for something like this would be to use a double buffering render strategy, but the issue may not be the render strategy but rather inefficiencies in your code, which are hard to pinpoint without seeing the code. Another thing you could do it only repaint the section(s) of the canvas that changed.

Comment: @StanvanderBend java swing does double buffering, it's better to not try and roll your own.

Comment: i'm going to try to create a minimal reproducible example as suggested and than i'll edit the question.

Comment: You really should have a drawing JPanel inside your JFrame.  The Oracle tutorial, [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) will show you how.

Comment: @matt Ah I wasn't aware of that, cheers. In the past I had made my own implementation using the awt.Canvas class for a game render engine where it solved flickering issues.

Comment: I just edited the question with an example

Comment: The problem is when i want to move the rect a lot of times, so i keep the right arrow on my keyboard pressed than the whole screen turn white until i stop pressing my keyboard.

Comment: Ok i will follow the tutorial and use your tips to solve it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making some strange mistakes. Don't extend JFrame it is pointless in this case.

Here is a start. You should probably use something other than a key listener, and make an action instead for the input map instead.

```
class ListFrame {
    ArrayList<Figure> figs = new ArrayList<Figure>();
    Random rand = new Random();

    ListFrame () {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        JPanel custom = new JPanel(){
           @Override
           public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
               super.paint(g);
               for (Figure fig: figs) {
                  fig.paint(g);
               }
           }
           @Override
           public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
               //you custom component should know it's preferred size.
               return new Dimension(350, 350); 
           } 
        };

        frame.addKeyListener (
            new KeyAdapter() {
                public void keyPressed (KeyEvent evt) {
                Dimension size = custom.getSize();
                
                int x = rand.nextInt(size.width);
                int y = rand.nextInt(size.height);
                int w = 5+ rand.nextInt(50);
                int h = 5+ rand.nextInt(50);
                if (evt.getKeyChar() == 'r') {
                    figs.add(new Rect(x,y, w,h));
                    } 
                else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP ) {
                    if (figs.size() > 0){
                        int dx = 0;
                        int dy = 0;
                        if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) dy = 2;
                        else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){ dy = -2;}
                        else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) dx = 2;
                        else if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) dx = -2;
                            
                        
                        Figure fig = figs.get(figs.size() -1);
                        fig.mov(dx,dy);
                        //You don't need to set the value. You modified it. 
                        //figs.set(figs.size() -1, fig);
                    }                
                }
                custom.repaint(); 
                
                }
                
            }
        );

        frame.setContentPane(custom);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle("Figures");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!!